# k3s/kubernetes, can not curl pod ip from different vendor vps node

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I create 4 nginx service, show:

```
kubectl get pods -o wide (hide some unimportant)
Test-nginx 1/1 Running 10.42.1.3 k8s-worker1
Test-nginx1 1/1 Running 10.42.1.6 k8s-worker1
Test-nginx3 1/1 Running 10.42.1.7 k8s-worker1
Test-nginx2 1/1 Running 10.42.0.9 k8s-master
```

Then i curl 10.42.1.3 on k8s-master, no response.
But i can curl 10.42.1.9 on k8s-master.
Also,i can't curl 10.42.1.9 on k8s-worker1.

k8s-master is Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS with iptables v1.8.4 (legacy).
k8s-worker1 is Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS with iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables)

Maybe this reason:
https://docs.k3s.io/installation/network-options#embedded-k3s-multicloud-solution

Comment: I have resolved this problem, just add a param --flannel-external-ip when install k3s, because of k8s-master and k8s-worker1 on different vendor vps。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pod ip is internal ip, can only access by other pod.

Here two simple way to access pod

- Use Port Forwarding to Access Applications in a Cluster

  ```
  kubectl port-forward pods/Test-nginx 8080:80
  ```

  Then open another terminal and run `curl http://k8s-master-ip:8080/`
- Use a Service to Access an Application in a Cluster

  ```
  # create node port service
  kubectl expose pod test-nginx --type=NodePort --port=80 --name=test-nginx-service
  # get nodeport
  NODEPORT=$(kubectl get service test-nginx-service -o jsonpath='{.spec.ports[0].nodePort}')
  # access
  curl http://k8s-master-ip:$NODEPORT/
  ```

other advanced way please see doc https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/.

Comment: I have resolved this problem, but thanks for you answer